# grails app deployed on JBoss give 404 status resource not found

Tags: grails, jboss, web.xml

deploying grails war on JBoss 4.2 sucessfully (following all the hacks to make it work)

```
INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/hello-0.1, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp2535731769294056658hello-0.1-exp.war/
WARN  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] Unable to process deployment descriptor for context '/hello-0.1'
```

but

```
http://myhostname:8080/hello-0.1/
```

gives a 404 error. I tried many different paths to hit a resource but to no avail

```
message /hello-0.1/
description The requested resource (/hello-0.1/) is not available.
```

it runs fine locally using grails run-app here:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello/hello/index
```

I have a feeling its something I need to set in web.xml or jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
        <context-root>hello-0.1</context-root>  
        <loader-repository>
            com.hello:archive=hello-0.1.war
            <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
        </loader-repository>
</jboss-web>
```

the log

```
2013-02-25 06:09:26,179 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/hello, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp8355669251173232249hello-exp.war/
2013-02-25 06:09:26,179 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] AbstractWebContainer.parseWebAppDescriptors, Begin
2013-02-25 06:09:26,180 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] Creating ENC using ClassLoader: java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@1731334
2013-02-25 06:09:26,180 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] ..org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3@b98fe1{ url=file:../jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp8355669251173232249hello-exp.war/ ,addedOrder=31}
2013-02-25 06:09:26,180 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] ..org.jboss.system.server.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@1dd7056
2013-02-25 06:09:26,180 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] ..sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@cac268
2013-02-25 06:09:26,180 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] ..sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@1a16869
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] Unable to retrieve orbjavax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: jboss:service=CorbaORB is not registered.
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] Linked java:comp/UserTransaction to JNDI name: UserTransaction
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] addEnvEntries
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] linkResourceEnvRefs
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] linkResourceRefs
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] linkMessageDestinationRefs
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] linkEjbRefs
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] linkEjbLocalRefs
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] linkServiceRefs
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] linkSecurityDomain
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] No security-domain given, using default: java:/jaas/other
2013-02-25 06:09:26,181 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] Linking security/securityMgr to JNDI name: java:/jaas/other
2013-02-25 06:09:26,182 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] AbstractWebContainer.parseWebAppDescriptors, End
2013-02-25 06:09:26,193 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] Using session cookies default setting
2013-02-25 06:09:26,453 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(/hello)
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.displayConfiguration' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.validateXml' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.verifyObjects' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.enableHtmlTagLibValidator' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.preferXHTML' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.compressViewState' - ENABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.compressJavaScript' - ENABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.externalizeJavaScript' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader' - ENABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.enableJSStyleHiding' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.enableScriptsInAttributeValues' - ENABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd' - ENABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.enableLazyBeanValidation' - ENABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,454 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.enabledLoadBundle11Compatibility' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.serializeServerState' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.enableViewStateIdRendering' - ENABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.registerConverterPropertyEditors' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.disableUnicodeEscaping' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1021: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.developmentMode' - DISABLED
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1018: [/hello] Configuration option 'javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD' set to 'server'
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1018: [/hello] Configuration option 'javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX' set to '.jsp'
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1018: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession' set to '15'
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1018: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews' set to '15'
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1018: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.injectionProvider' set to 'org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.injection.JBossInjectionProvider'
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1018: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.responseBufferSize' set to '1024'
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1018: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.clientStateWriteBufferSize' set to '8192'
2013-02-25 06:09:26,455 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] JSF1018: [/hello] Configuration option 'com.sun.faces.expressionFactory' set to 'com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl'
2013-02-25 06:09:26,461 DEBUG [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] No FacesServlet found in deployment descriptor - bypassing configuration
```

Comment: There is one other app running successfully on JBoss. I see the JBoss home pages at host:8080 but none of the JBoss management work all return 404 like the web or xms console

Comment: /server/default/work/jboss.web/localhost/hello-0.1/ has no org folder just tldCache.ser

Comment: successfully deployed web and JMX console

Comment: are you sure the webserver is running on port 8080 and not 80? Or maybe you have 2 different servers running on different ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally it appears you have your context root configured as `/hello`. When you deploy to JBoss, your `jboss-web.xml` is telling JBoss to use `hello-0.1` for the `context-root`.

You need to make your context roots match in both `Config.groovy`, which would have `grails.app.context` (or `app.context` in `application.properties`) and `context-root` in `jboss-web.xml`.

Comment: I tried changing everything (xml in war) to hello-0.1 and also to hello... still get 404. Did you mean BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: Nope, either `Config.groovy` or `application.properties`

Comment: changed everything from hello-0.1 to hello. Added app.context="hello" and context-root to be hello. Still get 404, no server errors and work directory /localhost/hello is empty

Answer (score 1):

Did you build the war and just drop it in the deploy directory? no hacks needed. from the docs:

**JBoss 4.2**

Deploying onto JBoss 4.2 is trivial, simply start-up JBoss then drop the WAR file into the JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy directory (or the relevant profile you want to deploy to). JBoss will automatically deploy the Grails application which will then be accessible via something like:

`http://localhost:8080/myapp-0.1`

http://grails.org/Deployment#JBoss%204.2

Comment: i wish it were that easy. It did not work, with and without hacks

Comment: What hacks are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: deleting log4j jar and adding jboss-web.xml  make it deploy with no errors, except the 404 not found page